# Locking rows correctly during user signup procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I'm pretty new to using `InnoDB` whilst utilising their locking mechanisms and I've encountered an issue I'm not so sure about.

Imagine you are creating a general user signup system, so user tries to register and you do something like this to check if their username they wanted is available:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='$username';
```

Then you find out the username is available so you go ahead and do this:

```
INSERT INTO users(username,email) VALUES('$username','$email');
```

Now what happens that in the very unlikely, but possible case that some other process checked for the same username *before* you inserted them into the database and they got the ok - obviously we don't want to end up with two users with the same username do we!?

So I thought of using a `FOR UPDATE` lock to prevent this, something like:

```
autocommit=0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='$username" FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO users(username,email) VALUES('$username','$email');
commit();
```

However I then realized, at least from what I understand that this wouldn't work because it would only lock the rows that the `SELECT` *found*; and since it is a `COUNT` it not referencing any specific rows, and even if you changed it to not using a `COUNT` it still wouldn't reference any rows as the username wouldn't be found.

If the above is right and it wouldn't work, the only thing I can think of is table level locking to prevent other processes from reading or writing to the table, but I know table level locks are very bad and should be avoided.

Is there a better way to do what I want to do without using table level locks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a [`UNIQUE` index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the `username` column. This way, if you attempt to `INSERT` a duplicate value for `username`, MySQL will keep the statement from executing and throw a duplicate error. Your program can catch this error (for details, see your client library's documentation) and ask the user to use a different username. You can distinguish a duplicate username from other error messages by the error code that MySQL returns to your client library.

Also make sure you [use parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) instead of substituting the username string directly into the SQL statement. Otherwise, malicious users will be able to [inject arbitrary SQL commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

Comment: Yeah I thought of doing that, but didn't like the fact of producing a generic error message; but I guess I can look for certain keywords in the mysql error to see if they have tried to insert a duplicate username or email. Oh and yes, I know to use parametrized queries, just did it like that for the purpose of an example :)